# recommendations for disk -> usb backup software

Tags: backup

Recently I lost a tape drive and rather than repair the unit I decided that backups to usb external drives would be cheaper.

In the past I used NTBackup and figured that the new server 2008 R2 backup wbadmin utility would be able to meet my needs. It does not. I am looking for recommendations for another utility that i can use.

My requirements are:
-backup local disk in addition to files on a network share
-scheduled task integration (or some gui options to manage schedule)
-non-incremental backup

Basically I could do this all with WBAdmin if it just supported network shares. I saw some links that described attaching a vhd pointed to a network share but I am trying to avoid hacks like that. If i'm going to do all that trouble I'd just as well manually copy the directories over myself.

If anyone has any software suggestions that might make this task easier for me let me know please. I am considering BackupAssist but can only find a few reviews here and there for it. I read one review about corrupting larger zip files during the backup so i'm hesitant. Also looking at Retrospect disk to disk 7.7.

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: I have a server 2008 standard and a server 2008 r2 box. Either will do.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had good experience with StorageCraft's ShadowProtect products for backing up servers and workstations.
http://www.shadowprotect.com/backup-software/shadowprotect-server

If I recall correctly, it has it's own GUI tool for setting schedules and can do full and incremental backups across network shares easily.

Comment: well, since my question got closed I ended up writing a massively long batch file which does exactly what I want. It's a shame that you can't ask advice from other experienced people on here regarding how to spend your money on something as important as reliable backup software. I trust here over most forums.